# Matched set without replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2012 database with structures represented as such:

- `TREATMENTA`: PATID bigint, AGE bigint, Weight bigint ;
- `TREATMENTB`: PATID bigint, AGE bigint, Weight bigint ;

I want to create a 1:1 matched set without replacement for `TREATMENTA` and `TREATMENTB` where `Age` difference between the matched pair is 30%.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Sample Data :
[image: TABLE TREATEMNTA]

[image: TABLE TREATMENTB]

[image: MATCHED RESULT]

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: At least try something. Start with a join because "match" implies that. What columns can be used for that purpose?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.